# Manually flush data to S3 in Fluentbit?

Tags: fluent-bit

When flushing to S3 failed more than `Retry_Limit`, the failed data remains in `store_dir`. Can I manually flush those data to S3 in Fluentbit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily force flushing the logs to AWS S3 by sending a SIGUSR1 to td-agent:

```
sudo kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/td-agent/td-agent.pid`
```

you should see a message like this in

> /var/log/td-agent/td-agent.conf

```
2019-08-11 14:43:18 +0000 [info]: #0 force flushing buffered events
2019-08-11 14:43:18 +0000 [info]: #0 flushing all buffer forcedly
```

https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/signals